# Add spaces between search bar dropdown options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add space between the different options in a dropdown list on a search bar. Currently, all of the options lump together, so that choosing a specific option is impossible and the words are in indecipherable. You can see the code/example at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fGdKs

I've tried messing with a lot of features of the CSS, such as margins, positions, and even trying to adjust the `.ui-autocomplete li`. The CSS is here:

```
input { 
    border: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 38px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:16pt;
}

.ui-menu-item {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:16pt;
    width: 500px;
    height: 26px;
    color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    border-color: #66b1ee;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    display: block;
    border: 5px outset transparent;
    top: 8px;
    display: block;
}
```

The searchbar HTML is as follows:

```
<label for="tags"><form class="searchbox ui-widget" action=""><input id="tags" type="search" placeholder="Select a programming language." /></label></form>
```

The Javascript is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
```

Thus, I need to add spaces between the different dropdown options, similar to suggestions/dropdown given by Google as search suggestions.

[image: Google Dropdown Menu Image]

Note: I'm using the jQuery ui library. 
See the pen at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fGdKs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `position:absolute;` from `.ui-menu-item` to stop each menu item overlaying on top of the last.

### [Demo CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lEczh)

```
.ui-menu-item {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size:16pt;
    width: 500px;
    height: 26px;
    color: blue;
    /* position: absolute;  <----remove! */
    border-color: #66b1ee;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
    display: block;
    border: 5px outset transparent;
    top: 8px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @maudulus - no worries :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:absolute` from your CSS and it will do the trick.

Absolute positions elements with reference to the browser starting point thus specifying this, you are telling it to place the elements at a fixed position wrt browser(0,0 by default).

Read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) for more details